# Is there a word from for a defect that is because of manipulation?

Tags: single-word-requests

We call a person/act/etc. that manipulates a *manipulative* person/act/etc.

Now I want to talk about a person who is manipulative and I want to say that she has a flaw which is that she is manipulative. I cannot say a *manipulative flaw* because that would mean the flaw manipulates itself. So how can I describe the flaw. I want one single word.

Personally, it seems to me that *manipulational* is the best option but I found that it has been used very rarely.

The/a manipulational flaw: a flaw because of being manipulative.

Compare for example *communicative* and *communicational*. A person is *communicative* who communicates well. So that person has *communicational* skills, skills related to communication.

Comment: You use 'a flaw which is that she is manipulative' as well as 'a flaw because of being manipulative', and the former makes more sense. 'Manipulative' is itself pejorative, and thus adequate. 'He is manipulative.' 'Communicational' is _not_ pejorative, so 'flaw' would be necessary. // If I saw 'He has a manipulational flaw' in a piece of work I was marking, would I knock a mark off for ungrammaticality / error in semantics per se? No. For non-idiomaticity / clunkiness? Yes.

Comment: Sounds like she is sneaky or devious.

Comment: I don't find your example helpful in trying to come up with anything, as I'd never say someone had "communicational skills". I'd say they have "communication skills".

Comment: @SteveLovell - But what about "vocational skills"?

Comment: You don't need the word you're looking for, because it is sufficient to say, "She is manipulative."  It is understood that this is a serious character flaw.

Comment: I agree that "vocational skills" is a good use of words, but it doesn't pin down an exact skill or set of skills, which means it isn't equivalent to the OPs request. I agree with you other comment. "She is manipulative" should be sufficient.

Comment: @SteveLovell But I want to make a title for the flaw. There is a section in my paper in which I am talking about the flaw and the title of that section is something like "manipulational flaw". And "manipulative flaw" sounds to me suggesting that the flaw itself manipulates.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It might depend on how 'chatty' you are happy for your (sub)titles to be and how uniform you need them across your work. So on some cases a title of "Being Manipulative" might be sufficient

Comment: It wouldn't be so transparent, but what about **The Machiavellian Flaw**?

Comment: Can you provide the phrasing you are trying to use? A fill in the blank statement.

Answer (score 1):

> **Manipulator**
> [muh-nip-yuh-ley-ter]/
> noun
>
> 1. a person who manipulates

Or

**manipulativeness**

*his **manipulativeness** is a flaw.*